# JAVA: BMI Calculator using

Tags: java, arraylist, double

I am very new to java trying to build a simple BMI calculator using a constructor, a public instance method and a toString method.

```
public class BMI {

public BMI(String name, double height, double weight){

}

public String getBMI() {
    return (weight/height);
  }


  public String toString() {
        return name + "is" + height + "tall and is " + weight +
                "and has a BMI of" + getBMI() ;
      }

public static void main(String[] args) {


}
```

i don't really know what i'm doing, so all help is appreciated. If you know how to complete this and can show me a main method which can demonstrate how to use it that would be even more appreciated.

thanks :)

Comment: How about borrowing a book like "Java for Beginners", or trying some introductionary tutorials? I'm honestly confused that at the time of writing this comment you already got two complete answers for showing ZERO effort. The usual response to this kind of inquiry is "What have you tried?" and "We don't offer complete solutions to homeworks.", but well.

Answer (score 0):

You have only local variables in constructor.

```
public class BMI {

String name;
double height, weight;

public BMI(String name, double height, double weight){
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
}

public double getBMI() {
    return (weight/height);
  }


  public String toString() {
        return name + "is" + height + "tall and is " + weight +
                "and has a BMI of" + getBMI() ;
      }

public static void main(String[] args) {
     BMI obj = new BMI("John",77,44);
     System.out.println(obj);
     //or
     double bmi = obj.getBMI();
     System.out.println("BMI = "+bmi);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a beginner I'm posting full code to get you going.

```
public class BMI {
String name;
double height;
double weight;
public BMI(String name, double height, double weight){
   this.name=name;
   this.height=height;
   this.weight=weight;
}

public String getBMI() {
    return (weight/height);
  }


  public String toString() {
        return name + "is" + height + "tall and is " + weight +
                "and has a BMI of" + getBMI() ;
      }

public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(new BMI("Sample",2,4));

}
```

**Output**

> Sample is 2 tall and is 4 and has a BMI of 2

Answer (score 0):

You already have a code so I'll just mention that BMI is weight (in kg) divided by height (in m) **squared**